# Error when build Ogre on Linux: narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, ogre

I am trying to get Ogre on Linux. I downloaded the source files and uncompressed them. Then I created the build folder then I ran "cmake ..". After that completed, I ran "make -j4" (I do have 4 cores and I have also tried just make). I get to 49% and it stops every time. I have downloaded the cmake gui and ran configure and checked all the boxes. I hit configure again and then generate. I tried running "make" again.

```
Downloads/ogre_src_v1-8-1/RenderSystems/GL/src/atifs/src/ps_‌​1_4.cpp:689:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘-35051’ from ‘int’ to ‘uint {aka unsigned int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing] };
```

That is the error that pops up several times except they refer to a different line of the code in ps_1_4.cpp and the number ‘-35051’ is different.

Also, There are several warnings for casting the const GLboolean* to GLboolean* throughout the build but this is the message that I have at the end:

```
RenderSystems/GL/CMakeFiles/RenderSystem_GL.dir/build.make:542: recipe for target 'RenderSystems/GL/CMakeFiles/RenderSystem_GL.dir/__/__/RenderSystem_GL/compile_RenderSystem_GL_0.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [RenderSystems/GL/CMakeFiles/RenderSystem_GL.dir/__/__/RenderSystem_GL/compile_RenderSystem_GL_0.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1057: recipe for target 'RenderSystems/GL/CMakeFiles/RenderSystem_GL.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [RenderSystems/GL/CMakeFiles/RenderSystem_GL.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also every time that I have tried a new way I delete the build folder and start all over. Each time it appears to end with this message. I am still relatively new to Linux and CMake, so can you explain what is going on and how you came to this conclusion?

**Note:** I have found [one forum that talks about this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1639264#p1639264) but I don't know where the build function is or how to change the CXX_FLAG.

Comment: `recipe for target * failed` **just** means that target are **failed** to build, without any information described reason of that failure. This information has a little sence when debugging the problem. As for error message `Recipe for target 'all' failed` in the title, this message appears for **any error** in **any make build**. If you want to obtain more valuable info, use single-threaded `make -j1` and look for lines contained `Error` or similar.

Comment: I did that and the only errors that I see are several errors like this: `Downloads/ogre_src_v1-8-1/RenderSystems/GL/src/atifs/src/ps_1_4.cpp:689:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘-35051’ from ‘int’ to ‘uint {aka unsigned int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
 };
 ^
`

Comment: So, these errors are **actual** description of failure you get. Add them **into your question**, as all valuable information should be in the question post, not in the comments.

Comment: I also added that a I found a forum that has a solution but it isn't as descriptive as I need it to be. I don't know where the build function is/goes.

Comment: `I don't know where the build function is/goes.` - In the referred post "build function" is the one which calls `cmake`. And it suggests to set (modify) *CXXFLAGS* variable before this call. As you call `cmake` manually, you need to set variable in the same terminal before the call: `export CXXFLAGS+=' -std=gnu++98'`. Alternatively, you may modify compiler flags in the `cmake` call: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--std=gnu++98" ..`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The following command that you gave `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--std=gnu++98" ..` worked. If you want to "Answer" the question using that, I'll select it as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Referenced post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1639131#p1639131) suggests that Ogre can be successfully built using `gnu++98` standard (which is actually a `c++98` plus GNU extensions).

The standard is set via compiler flags, in case of `cmake` flags may be passed as:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--std=gnu++98" ..
```